# Random Walk of a Photon Through the Sun

Tags: python, physics

For a project, I am trying to determine the time it would take for a photon to leave the Sun. However, I am having trouble with my code (found below).

More specifically, I set up a for loop with an if statement, and if some randomly generated probability is less than the probability of collision, that means the photon collides and it changes direction.

What I am having trouble with is setting up a condition where the for loop stops if the photon escapes (when distance > Sun radius). The one I have set up already doesn't appear to work.

I use a very scaled down measurement of the Sun's radius because if I didn't it would take a long time for the photon to escape in my simulation.

```
    from numpy.random import random as rng # we want them random numbers
    import numpy as np # for the math functions
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # to make pretty pretty class

    mass_proton = 1.67e-27
    mass_electron = 9.11e-31
    Thompson_cross = 6.65e-29
    Sun_density = 150000
    Sun_radius = .005

    Mean_Free = (mass_proton + mass_electron)/(Thompson_cross*Sun_density*np.sqrt(2))

    time_step= 10**-13 # Used this specifically in order for the path length to be < Mean free Path
    path_length = (3e8)*time_step


    Probability = 1-np.exp(-path_length/Mean_Free) # Probability of the photon colliding


    def Random_walk():
        x = 0   # Start at origin (0,0)
        y = 0
        N = 1000
        m=0 # This is a counter I have set up for the number of collisions

        for i in range(1,N+1): 
            prand = rng(N+1)    # Randomly generated probability

            if prand[i] < Probability:  # If my prand is less than the probability
                                # of collision, the photon collides and changes
                                # direction
                x += Mean_Free*np.cos(2*np.pi*prand)    
                y += Mean_Free*np.sin(2*np.pi*prand)    
                m += 1  # Everytime a collision occurs 1 is added to my collision counter


            distance = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # Final distance the photon covers

            if np.all(distance) > Sun_radius:   # if the distance the photon travels
                break                           # is greater than the Radius of the Sun,
                                        # the for loop stops, meaning the 
                                        #photon escaped

        print(m)    

        return x,y,distance


    x,y,d = Random_walk()
    plt.plot(x,y, '--')
    plt.plot(x[-1], y[-1], 'ro')
```

Any criticisms of my code are welcome, this is for a grade and I do want to learn how to do this correctly, so please tell me if you notice any other errors.

Comment: Since `distance` seems to be an `ndarray`, your if statement should read: `if np.all(distance > Sun_radius):`. For the moment you a comparing an integer/float to a boolean.

Comment: @domochevski `distance` seems to be a float to me. Seems like it should just be `if distance > Sun_radius`.

Comment: @domochevski Thank you! This solved another question I had.

Comment: Are you supposed to consider the sun as a 3-dimensional object?  If so you would have to keep track of the photon's position and direction in three dimensions, not two as you are doing.  BTW, each step through your loop the photon moves a distance=path_length, not =Mean_Free.  And you aren't handling the condition where the photon does not collide (i.e., when your if statement is false),

Comment: @PaulCornelius What would my else statement be? If the photon does not collide there is no need for it to change direction so it would just be moving in the same direction

Comment: You use the value of x and y to figure out when you've left the sun.  But you don't change x and y unless your if statement is true, so how do x and y change while the photon keeps moving in the same direction?  I've used np very little, so I'm not sure I understand your code.  Are x and y scalars or arrays?

Comment: @PaulCornelius My x and y are lists. What condition would you put? else: x = x[-1] y = y[-1]?

Comment: Then it seems to me that you are extending those arrays only when there is a collision, and therefore the continuing straight-line motion of the photon is not appearing in your model.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Oh I see, then in that case when the photon does not collide, then the photon will continue moving in the same direction and in the same path_length intervals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the motivation for the formulas you've implemented. I'll explain my own motivation here, but if your instructor told you to do something else, I guess you should listen to them instead.

If I were going to do this, I would generate a sequence of movements of a photon, stopping when distance of the photon to the center of the sun is greater than the solar radius. Each movement is a sample from a distribution which has two components: one for the distance, and one for the direction. I will assume that these are independent (this may be questioned in a more careful simulation).

It seems plausible that the distribution of distance is an exponential distribution with parameter 1/(mean free path). Then the density is p(d) = (1/MFP) exp(-d/MFP). Its cdf is 1 - exp(-d/MFP) and the inverse of the cdf is -MFP log(1 - p) where p = cdf(d). Now you can sample from the distribution of distances: let p = rand(0, 1) where rand = uniform random and plug it into the inverse cdf to get d. This is called the inverse cdf method of sampling; a web search will find more info about it.

As for the direction, you can let angle = rand(0, 2*pi) and then (x, y) = (cos(angle), sin(angle)).

Now you can construct the series of positions. From an initial location, let the new location = previous + d*(x, y). Stop when distance of location to center is greater than radius.

Looks like a great problem! Good luck and have fun. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What is d? Is it the total distance traveled? Also thank you for answering!

Comment: The photon keeps moving in the same direction until it undergoes a collision.  Only when it collides do you randomly set a new direction, otherwise you compute its new position based on the previous direction.  There is no distribution of distances since the photon always moves the same distance during each step.

Comment: @LA495 d is the distance traveled between one collision and the next.

Comment: @PaulCornelius OK, I see now what OP was getting at about repeated steps. But if one takes a step, decides if there is a collision with constant probability, takes another step, etc., then the number of steps until a collision has a geometric distribution, and for small steps, the density of the distance traveled between collisions approaches an exponential. In that sense I guess the two approaches are equivalent, although I would argue there's an advantage to just having one step per path segment instead of multiple steps per segment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of thinking about the problem that you may find helpful.  At each moment, the photon has a position (x, y) and a direction (dx, dy).  The (dx, dy) variables are coefficients of the unit vector, so `sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2) = 1.0`.  The distance traveled by the photon during one step is path_length * direction.

At each step you do 4 things:

1. calculate the photon's new position
2. figure out if the photon has left the sun by computing its distance from the center point
3. determine, with a single random number, whether or not the photon collides.  If it does you randomly generate a new direction.
4. Append the photon's current position to a list.  You might want to do this as a function of distance from the center rather than x,y.

At the end, you plot the list you have built up.

You should also choose a random direction at the very start.

I don't know how you will terminate the loop, for the photon isn't ever guaranteed to leave the sun - just like in the real world.  In principle the program might run forever (or until the sun burns out).

There is a slight inaccuracy in that the photon can collide at any instant, not just at the end of one step.  But since the steps are small, so is the error introduced by this simplification.

I will point out that you do not need numpy for any of this except perhaps the final plot.  The standard Python library has all the math functions you need.  Numpy is of course great for manipulating arrays of data, but the only array you will have here is the one you build, a step at a time, of photon position versus time.

As I pointed out in one of my comments, you are modeling the sun as a 2-dimensional object.  If you want to do this calculation in three dimensions, you don't need to change this basic approach.